# How queries on unsaved data work in Core Data with SQLite store?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, core-data

Until managed object context is sent `save:` message, modifications made to managed objects are only in memory and not committed to the database. How it performs queries on the database then? It has to perform standard SQL query, then query on unsaved objects and merge results, and this should be very slow.

UPDATE:
For example, I have Article <-> Tag many-to-many relationship and I have number of unsaved Articles. Then I want to find all articles having some tag or between some dates. In database this would be a query on our relationship table or on date field and will use appropriate indexes. But for unsaved objects it would have to iterate over all unsaved articles and/or their tags? Or for unsaved objects it also has some database-like storage?

Answer (score 1):

By default Core Data won't query pending changes when you perform a fetch - you need to explicitly set this by using the `setIncludesPendingChanges` property of the fetch request.

Assuming you have enabled this: I'm not sure why you think it would be any slower querying the unsaved changes.

If your Core Data instance is backed by an SQLite store then you'll need to read the database off the persistent storage (disc). Your unsaved objects will all still be in RAM - it's considerably faster to access those unsaved objects than it is to access the objects in the DB. You can do these two queries in parallel and then merge the results - merging an array is trivial - meaning there's virtually no performance penalty.

All always there are exceptions and edge cases, but generally speaking there should be no noticeable performance penalty.

Comment: SQLite engine is real database engine, so it has indexes, can perform joins, etc. So if we're talking about relatively large number of unsaved obejcts it is faster to query DB than to filter bunch of in-memory objects where there's no indexes, to-many relations are stored as `NSSet`s and so on. By the way, `setIncludesPendingChanges` is set to YES by default.

Comment: Ah, but your unsaved objects almost certainly *aren't* simply in a `NSSet`. They'll be stored as a graph, since that's what Core Data is all about, including information about their relationships.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question, and I do wonder how efficient large fetches are when a bunch of objects are in memory.

My guess is that the objects in memory are managed rather intelligently and that the object graphs are setup in a way such that the overhead of fetch requests is minimized. While it MIGHT be slightly less efficient that if all objects had been written to the disk (only because of the "double fetch"), overall the benefits of having the memory layer and not having to constantly be writing to and reading from the disk would heavily outweigh the slight drop in performance of these types of fetch requests.

I think the only way you are going to get an answer to this question is to do some analysis yourself. If you open Instruments, the iOS Simulator has a Core Data instrument that can help you analyze fetch requests. I would test out the difference between executing the same fetch twice: once with all pending changes processed before the fetch, and once with a bunch of objects in memory. If you do this I would love to see the results of the two fetches!